# How to call a function from a different frame using ActionScript 2.0?

Tags: flash, function, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I am looking for a way to call a function defined in a different frame in ActionScript 2.0. The details are as follows:

**As a button event in frame 1, I have:**

```
on (release)
{
   _root.gotoAndStop(2); //Going to Frame 2.
   selectVideo(5); //Calling a function defined in Frame 2. 
   //Calling this function is not working in the way i wrote it above. 
}
```

**On Frame 2, I have the following script on the frame itself:**

```
var vlist:XML = new XML(); //Creating an XML variable
vlist.ignoreWhite = true; //Ignoring the white spaces in the xml
vlist.load("videoList.xml"); //Loading a list of videos from the xml.

vlist.onLoad = function() 
{
   var videos:Array = this.firstChild.childNodes;
   for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++)
   {
      vidList.addItem({label:videos[i].attributes.desc, data:videos[i].attributes.url});
   }

   vid.load(vidList.getItemAt(0).data);
   vidList.selectedIndex = 0;

   //Notes:
   //vid: is an instance of (FLVPlayback) component. 
   //vidList: is an instance of a (List) component. 
};

function selectVideo(index:Number) 
{
   //Here is the function that i want to call from frame 1 but it is not getting called.
   vidList.selectedIndex = index;
}

var listHandler:Object = new Object();
listHandler.change = function(evt:Object)
{
    vid.load(vidList.getItemAt(vidList.selectedIndex).data);
};

vidList.addEventListener("change",listHandler);
```

For some reason, the code on frame 2 is working by itself but selecting an index from the list from another frame is not working. In other words, I am not able to successfully call `selectVideo()` from frame 1 while it is defined in frame 2.

The objective of the program, as implied, is referring to a certain video from the list from a different frame. The whole code is working without errors, I'm just not able to select a video from the list and play it if it was initially in a different previous frame.

Any ideas, suggestions or solutions are highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Dairo When editing a post, please fix everything, not just one typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first: timeline scripting is a mess, try using classes instead.

you could try and set a variable on `_root`. something like `_root.nextIndex = 5;` and then change the frame to 2.

```
on (release)
{
   _root.nextIndex = 5;
   _root.gotoAndStop(2); //Going to Frame 2.
}
```

then either call the function and pass it the `_root.nextIndex` or remove the function completely and just do the

```
vidList.selectedIndex = _root.nextIndex;
```

outside of any function.

Comment: Your notes were highly appreciated. Thanks for the presented solution as well. It is working perfectly now. This is the only timeline scripting that i have in the whole application. The above code is just made solely for the question. My source code is very much different that that. Indeed, using classes is essential.

Answer (score 1):

This is the quick fix for your code (you were lacking the _root to access the main timeline on the function call):

```
on (release)
{
   _root.gotoAndStop(2); //Going to Frame 2.
   _root.selectVideo(5); //Calling a function defined on the timeline in Frame 2. 

}
```

But I would try to follow pkyeck's advice and try to limit the script added on different frames in the timeline, as it can get really messy.

Comment: Pkyeck's code is working but your way is leading to the same problem that i was facing before. However, that's due to the way i programmed my small application. However, your concept is perfectly right. (+1 for your help)